# AWS Lambda Authorizer caches more than token expiry

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I have a lambda authorizer and its cache is set to 300 seconds. If the incoming token is about to expire let's say in 30 seconds, when it is validated and cached on APIGW/authorizer, it will be working 230 more seconds after its expiry due to 300 seconds cached result. Do you know is there any way to make the cache TTL time based on the token expiry if the token's expiration time is less then configured cache TTL?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you can do is to verify the expiration threshold in the lambda authorizer from the token, if possible.

For example: if the received token is a JWT token, decode & extract the "exp" claim from it. Return a deny policy, if the expiry will hit before next 300 seconds, based on the extracted claim.

This would ensure, that every cached token will be valid for at least the required 5 minutes.